# Can't unlock address when using ganache-cli

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, ganache-cli

I want to unlock an address and fund it with ETH in ganache that I don't have its private key. So I run this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ganache-cli --hardfork istanbul --port 8545 --gasLimit 8000000 --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxxxx -e 1000000 -u 0x42665308F611b022df2fD48757A457BEC12BA668
```

However, I get: `Error: Returned error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 7000000 and the sender's account only has: 0` when I want to send tx with the address. Please help.

Comment: Right. You obviously cannot unlock your account on a public node like Infura. You don't want to do that either!

Comment: I'm using ganache, so my purpose is just to grant access to a certain address that I don't actually have its a private key to simulate some mainnet tx in ganache.

Comment: BTW, the error that you're getting implies that the problem is not because you're unable to unlock some account, but because you have 0 ether on it.

Comment: Oh! I think I get it. I think `-e 1000000` will also fund the unlock address but actually it will not.

Answer (score 1):

The address is actually unlocked but doesn't have enough ETH. So I need to send a tx to fund the address. I think `-e 1000000` will also fund the unlock address but actually it will not and that' my mistake.